# Is it possible to create a reference partitioned table with an interval partitioned parent table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

According to ORA-14659, Oracle 11g currently doesn't support creation of reference-partitioned table with an interval partitioned parent table. But am wondering if it is possible to do that with some workarounds? Any input will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to create a reference partitioned table off an interval partitioned parent. However, you can certainly create a reference partitioned table from a RANGE partitioned parent.  I blogged about this before:

http://betteratoracle.com/posts/21-11g-reference-partitioning

What is your partition interval in the parent table? Can you easily change it to be range partitioned?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen!

My parent table is using range-list partition (interval partitioned by year and sub-partitioned by list of 12 months), the whole point of doing this initially was to save DBA the trouble of manually adding new partition every year. Now that I think about it, your suggestion might be the best solution for now, it could be too ambitious an attempt to automate the creation of year partition at this point.

Comment: I'll opt for creating sufficient amount of year partitions using range partition.

But still, as far as I'm concerned creating reference partition table off interval partitioned parent table is a very common case, hope the next version of oracle will address this issue.

Comment: In Oracle 11G and above (which I assume you are using due to using the interval partitioning feature), if you attempt to insert into a partition that does not exist, Oracle will go ahead and create it for you. I cannot recall if it is interval partitioning or range partitioning that does this. I agree that interval and reference partitioning should work well together, so hopefully a new version will add that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Now, in Oracle 12c, you can create [interval reference partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17613/part_admin001.htm#VLDBG14103).